# How to make sequelize has many association lowercase in views

Tags: mysql, express, handlebars.js, sequelize.js

Everything works here. The only issue is that in my handlebars file, I have to get to a person's tasks like this:

```
this.Tasks
```

I would rather have it appear like this:

```
this.tasks
```

How would I customize Sequelize to do so?

This is what the root route of my app looks like (it's rendering the index.handlebars file)

[image: project management app]

my route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  models.Person.findAll({
    include: [ models.Task ]
  }).then(function(people) {
    res.render('index', {
      user_id: req.session.user_id,
      email: req.session.user_email,
      logged_in: req.session.logged_in,
      people: people
    });
  });
});
```

my index.handlebars file:

```
  {{#each people}}
    <li>
      {{this.name}}
      {{#if ../logged_in}}
        <a href="/people/{{this.id}}/destroy"> destroy</a>
      {{/if}}
      <ul>
        {{#if ../logged_in}}
          <li>
            <form action="/people/{{this.id}}/tasks/create" method="POST" style="display: inline">
              <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="add task here">
              <input type="submit" value"assign task">
            </form>
          </li>
        {{/if}}

        {{#each this.Tasks }}
          <li>
            {{this.task}}
            {{#if ../../logged_in}}
              <a href="/people/{{this.person_id}}/tasks/{{this.id}}/destroy">destroy</a>
            {{/if}}
          </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
```

my people table migration:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface
      .createTable('people', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
        },
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        created_at: Sequelize.DATE,
        updated_at: Sequelize.DATE
      });
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface
      .dropTable('people');
  }
};
```

my tasks table migration:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface
      .createTable('tasks', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
        },
        person_id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        task: Sequelize.STRING,
        created_at: Sequelize.DATE,
        updated_at: Sequelize.DATE
      });
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface
      .dropTable('tasks');
  }
};
```

my person.js model:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Person = sequelize.define("Person", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'people',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Person.hasMany(models.Task)
      }
    }
  });

  return Person;
};
```

my task.js model:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
    task: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'tasks',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Task.belongsTo(models.Person, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return Task;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using lowercase name for sequelize.define you can also set the name via alias using 'as' option. Ex. `Task.belongsTo(models.Person, {as: 'task'});`. Alternatively, you can set the alias in the define function itself. Ex. 
`sequelize.define("Task", attributes, 
    {
       name : {
         singular: "task",
         plural: "tasks"
    })`

Answer (score 0):

> > my task.js model:
> >
> > ```
> > module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
> > var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
> > ```

Just specify

```
var task = sequelize.define("task", {
```

Didn't it solves you question?

Answer (score 0):

define model name in lowercase as

> var Task = sequelize.define("task", {